# Symfony, access to getManager() into controller

Tags: symfony

So, for now, i get my manager in each action on my controller like that :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

Is there a better way to do that ? Use __construct and an attribut $em ? Don't know ? I want to reduce the size of my code.. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it:

create private method:

```
private function manager()
{
    return $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
}
```

then, in your action:

```
$em = $this->manager();
```

or directly:

```
$this->manager()->persist();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the `setContainer` method in your child class and set the manager as a class property:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    protected $manager;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->manager = $container->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    }
}
```

Of course, if you find yourself using the manager in a lot of methods, maybe it's time to put all that logic into a service and use proper dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep your controller leaner, can also write your Model Manager. But this is not new and not my idea. You can find some of the same solutions on the Internet.

Let's call our entity "Comment" and the Controller "CommentController".

1) Our ModelMananger is implemented against the following interface:

```
<?php

namespace Sg\ExampleBundle\Doctrine\ModelManager;

interface ModelManagerInterface
{
    /**
     * Creates an empty object instance.
     *
     * @return object
     */
    function create();

    /**
     * Saves an object.
     *
     * @param object  $object   An object instance
     * @param boolean $andFlush Whether to flush the changes (default true)
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function save($object, $andFlush = true);

    /**
     * Removes an object.
     *
     * @param object  $object   An object instance
     * @param boolean $andFlush Whether to flush the changes (default true)
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function remove($object, $andFlush = true);

    /**
     * Finds many objects by the given criteria.
     *
     * @param array $criteria
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function findBy(array $criteria = array());

    /**
     * Finds one object by the given criteria.
     *
     * @param array $criteria
     *
     * @return object|null
     */
    function findOneBy(array $criteria = array());

    /**
     * Finds an object by its primary key / identifier.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The identifier
     *
     * @return object
     */
    function find($id);

    /**
     * Write all changes to the database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function flushAllChanges();

    /**
     * Returns the objects's fully qualified class name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function getClass();
}
```

2) Now I use an abstract class to implement common functions:

```
<?php

namespace Sg\ExampleBundle\Doctrine\ModelManager;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

abstract class AbstractModelManager implements ModelManagerInterface
{
    /**
     * The fully qualified class name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $class;

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    protected $repository;


    //-------------------------------------------------
    // Ctor.
    //-------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Ctor.
     *
     * @param EntityManager $em    An EntityManager instance
     * @param string        $class The class name
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $class)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->repository = $em->getRepository($class);

        $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata($class);
        $this->class = $metadata->getName();
    }


    //-------------------------------------------------
    // ModelManagerInterface
    //-------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $class = $this->class;
        $object = new $class();

        return $object;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function save($object, $andFlush = true)
    {
        $this->em->persist($object);

        if (true === $andFlush) {
            $this->flushAllChanges();
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function remove($object, $andFlush = true)
    {
        $this->em->remove($object);

        if (true === $andFlush) {
            $this->flushAllChanges();
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function findBy(array $criteria = array())
    {
        return $this->repository->findBy($criteria);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function findOneBy(array $criteria = array())
    {
        return $this->repository->findOneBy($criteria);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function find($id)
    {
        return $this->repository->find($id);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function flushAllChanges()
    {
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getClass()
    {
        return $this->class;
    }
}
```

3) Special functions come in the CommentModelManager:

```
<?php

namespace Sg\ExampleBundle\Doctrine\ModelManager;

use Sg\ExampleBundle\Doctrine\ModelManager\AbstractModelManager as BaseModelManager;
use Sg\ExampleBundle\Entity\User;

class CommentModelManager extends BaseModelManager
{
    /**
     * Find all Comments by given User.
     *
     * @param User $user
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function findCommentsByUser(User $user)
    {
        $qb = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $qb->where('c.createdBy = :user');
        $qb->setParameter('user', $user);

        return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    }
}
```

4) Register the CommentModelManager in your services.yml:

```
services:

# ModelManager

sg_example.doctrine.model_manager.comment:
    class: Sg\ExampleBundle\Doctrine\ModelManager\CommentModelManager
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, 'Sg\ExampleBundle\Entity\Comment']
# ...
```

5) Use the CommentModelManager in your CommentModel like:

```
<?php

namespace Sg\ExampleBundle\Controller;

use Sg\ExampleBundle\Entity\Comment;

// ...

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    // ..

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $userComments = $this->getCommentModelManager()->findCommentsByUser($this->getUser());

        return array(
            'entities' => $userComments 
        );
    }

    /**
     * Shortcut to return the Comment Model Manager service.
     * 
     * @return \Sg\ChiliManBundle\Doctrine\ModelManager\ChiliModelManager
     */
    protected function getCommentModelManager()
    {
        return $this->container->get('sg_example.doctrine.model_manager.comment');
    }
}
```